# wordpress search custom post type in post meta fields and another custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, query-optimization

Need help with searching alternatives of wordpress custom post type 'product' having 3 postmeta fields

```
postmeta Keys
key 1 = 'Short Description'
key 2 = 'Long Description'
key 3 = 'Cat '
```

Where meta_value of "key 3" is the serialized IDs of custom_post_type 'ProductCategories'

I need to search in ((key1 or key2 ) AND key 3)
That is user searched a product name in a selected category so either short description or long description and in a particular category

THE FOLLOWING QUERY AM USING IS NOT VERY QUICK AND TAKES 45+ SECONDS WHICH IS NOT TOLERABLE

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.ID, posts.post_content, 
                        posts.post_title, meta.meta_key, meta.meta_value, 
                        meta.post_id 
                        FROM wsh_posts posts
                        LEFT JOIN wsh_postmeta meta
                        ON posts.ID = meta.post_id
                        RIGHT JOIN wsh_postmeta cat 
                        ON cat.post_id = posts.ID 
                        WHERE posts.post_type = "product" 
                        AND posts.post_status = "publish"
                AND
                (
                     (
                            cat.meta_value REGEXP("(.*)117124(.*)|(.*)117136(.*)|(.*)117135(.*)|(.*)117091(.*)|(.*)117083(.*)|(.*)117080(.*)|(.*)117113(.*)|(.*)111516(.*)|(.*)111180(.*)|(.*)108030(.*)|(.*)108031(.*)|(.*)116316(.*)|(.*)114867(.*)|(.*)114251(.*)|(.*)113220(.*)|(.*)113201(.*)|(.*)108109(.*)|(.*)108057(.*)|(.*)114925(.*)|(.*)114805(.*)|(.*)114665(.*)|(.*)114654(.*)|(.*)114167(.*)|(.*)113981(.*)|(.*)113929(.*)|(.*)113845(.*)|(.*)114881(.*)|(.*)113897(.*)|(.*)113846(.*)|(.*)113465(.*)|(.*)113255(.*)|(.*)112907(.*)|(.*)112861(.*)|(.*)117100(.*)|(.*)117098(.*)|(.*)117096(.*)|(.*)117093(.*)|(.*)116261(.*)|(.*)114383(.*)|(.*)112875(.*)|(.*)112862(.*)|(.*)112603(.*)|(.*)112276(.*)|(.*)112057(.*)|(.*)111880(.*)|(.*)111776(.*)|(.*)111658(.*)|(.*)117105(.*)|(.*)116426(.*)|(.*)116387(.*)|(.*)116305(.*)|(.*)111771(.*)|(.*)111746(.*)|(.*)111695(.*)|(.*)111674(.*)|(.*)111663(.*)|(.*)111659(.*)|(.*)111655(.*)|(.*)111493(.*)|(.*)111467(.*)|(.*)111442(.*)|(.*)111367(.*)|(.*)111259(.*)|(.*)111231(.*)|(.*)111210(.*)|(.*)111204(.*)|(.*)111205(.*)|(.*)110978(.*)|(.*)111096(.*)|(.*)110929(.*)|(.*)110680(.*)|(.*)110475(.*)|(.*)110422(.*)|(.*)117078(.*)|(.*)110423(.*)|(.*)110245(.*)|(.*)110209(.*)|(.*)110186(.*)|(.*)113776(.*)|(.*)113662(.*)|(.*)112226(.*)|(.*)112193(.*)|(.*)112139(.*)|(.*)112109(.*)|(.*)110687(.*)|(.*)110673(.*)|(.*)110649(.*)|(.*)110626(.*)|(.*)110611(.*)|(.*)110345(.*)|(.*)110333(.*)|(.*)110187(.*)|(.*)109741(.*)|(.*)109603(.*)|(.*)109052(.*)|(.*)108665(.*)|(.*)108644(.*)|(.*)108442(.*)|(.*)108415(.*)|(.*)108271(.*)|(.*)115656(.*)|(.*)115647(.*)|(.*)108217(.*)|(.*)108163(.*)|(.*)108159(.*)|(.*)108006(.*)|(.*)107873(.*)|(.*)107784(.*)|(.*)110889(.*)|(.*)110852(.*)|(.*)108150(.*)|(.*)107888(.*)|(.*)107789(.*)|(.*)107785(.*)|(.*)107680(.*)|(.*)115191(.*)|(.*)111874(.*)|(.*)107767(.*)|(.*)107706(.*)|(.*)107698(.*)|(.*)107659(.*)|(.*)107645(.*)|(.*)112664(.*)|(.*)112176(.*)|(.*)109335(.*)|(.*)109263(.*)|(.*)109111(.*)|(.*)109065(.*)|(.*)107646(.*)|(.*)107644(.*)") 
                            AND cat.meta_key = "cat"
                    )
                    AND 
                    (
                        (
                            meta.meta_key = "shortDescription" 
                            OR meta.meta_key = "longDescription"
                        )
                        AND (
                            meta.meta_value LIKE "%beanies%" 
                            OR posts.post_title LIKE "%beanies%" 
                            OR posts.post_content LIKE "%beanies%"
                        )
                    )
                ) GROUP BY posts.ID
                   LIMIT 0, 35
```

Comment: That regexp pattern match is certainly the issue here. There's no better way to define this?

Comment: you want me to explain the problem ?? why i am using regex ?

Comment: I have used regex because the Custom Post Type (CPT) 'ProductCategory' association with CPT 'Product' is done using meta_key 'Cat' which is searlized. So no other way of doing this ....IF you can help me have a  meta_query with multiple relations that might also help